# Difference between ->withIndex($index) and ->with('index',$index) in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I just came accros a variable defined as `->with('index',$index)` and I was wandering, is there a difference between this format and this one I usually use : 
`->withIndex($index)`?

If yes, which one should be promote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that **with()** can accept an array with variables, for example `->with(['index' => $index]);` and by `->withParamName();` you pass only one variable. Behind the scenes Laravel calls a magic method and transforms the `withIndex($index)` to `with('index',$index)`, so you can use either. Just make sure you don't use a reserved method name like *withHeaders, withCookie, withInput*, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !